# Stopping Thread in another event

Tags: android, multithreading

My problem is... 
I have 2 events.. onCreate and Onclick. I have a thread running inside onCreate and i have to stop it inside onClick. Is this possible?
If yes, please provide me with some hints/ code snippets how to implement this.

My code inside onCreate event is this:-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        try{
            bright = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), 
                     Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                bright = 1.0f;
            }


        lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
         new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            lp.screenBrightness= dim;
                            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                            // SLEEP 2 SECONDS HERE ...
                            final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                            Timer t = new Timer(); 

                            t.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
                                    public void run() { 
                                            handler.post(new Runnable() { 
                                                    public void run() { 
                                                    lp.screenBrightness=bright;
                                                    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                                                    } 
                                            }); 
                                    } 
                            }, 2000); 

                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }

        }

      }).start();  

    }
```

this activity is running inside a loop. And i want to stop this wen i click on the button. It seems that i cannot call the Thread.interrupt() method inside the button onclick event. How do i proceed with this?

Comment: [android best and safe way to stop thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505707/android-best-and-safe-way-to-stop-thread)

Comment: @Bhuro: i've updated my question. thanks for the link anyways

Comment: FWIW, creating a Handler and a Timer and a TimerTask seems like overkill. Could omit Timer and TimerTask, just do `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {..}, 2000);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare an `boolean`  `mRunnning` in your class, this is like a flag, and custom running thread will depend on this to know if it has been cancelled.
2. As usual, you have a loop in your thread, instead of `while(true)` do `while(mRunning)`.
3. Also, you are making your thread sleep, during sleep, thread won't be able to check on `mRunning` variable, you will have to call `interrupt()` on thread object to make it stop.
4. It will be better to use a variable to hold thread reference `Thread t = new Thread(....`
5. So, now to stop your thread you have to call `mRunning = false` and then `t.interrupt()`.

Comment: when i use the thread reference myThread = new Thread(new Runnable...   , i get this message showing "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Thread"

Answer (score 1):

If you create a reference you can access it from everywhere in you class. So, in the class body ad something like

```
Thread thrd
```

Just like you would do so with a Button, TextView, or whatever. Then in the onCreate method add the reference like

```
thrd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
```

Now you have a reference to your thread you can use everywhere in your class.

Comment: when i try this myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){,  i get this message "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Thread"

Answer (score 1):

according to your current situation based on previous answer comment . you r trying like:

```
myThread = new Thread(new Runnable
```

right?

then u should also delete `.start();` part of your previous coding. then write:

```
myThread.start();
```

u should declare `myThread` as global in your class, so that u can access this thread from anywhere in your class. now u can stop thread in `onClick`

u should combine this answer and `User117` s answer together .

Answer (score 0):

instead of
         while(true)

inside the run() Method, declare a boolean variable to true and change it after onClick. For example:

```
     private boolean shouldRun = true;
```

then in the run() method:

```
      @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (shouldRun==true) {
                     .
                     . 
                     .
```

and in your onClick:

```
        @override
          public void OnClick(View v){

              shouldRun=false;
                      .
                      .
                      .
```

Comment: when i use the thread reference myThread = new Thread(new Runnable... , i get this message showing "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Thread"