# How can I terminate thread properly in Android System?

Tags: android, multithreading, terminate

I have a question. 
Recently I develop simple "Logging system" for Android. 
There is one singleton class which name is "Logger".

```
protected Logger(){
....
_logHandler = new LogHandler(_logQueue);
_logHandler.start();
.... 
}
public static Logger getInstance(){
    ...
}
```

In "Logger", one thread is running just like below.

```
@Override
public void run() {
   try{
        while (isAlive){
            execute();                     
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    while (isPaused) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    shutDown();
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        shutDown();
    }
}
public void requestShutDown(){
    isAlive = false;
    interrupt();
}
```

What i want is when application is terminated, I would like to call "requestShutDown()" method to stop thread above.
But i can't find proper moment.

So, Do I have to 
When onPause() method executed in Activity, call requestShutDown(). And onResume() method executed in Activity, call thread.start() again?

Is there another way?

Or When Application is terminated, all the resources in application(include thread, Logger class in above) are garbage collected properly?

thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505707/android-best-and-safe-way-to-stop-thread

Comment: maybe on `onDestroy()` in your MainActivity ?!

Comment: @RiddhiShah thanks, i'll see it

Comment: @dwnz Thanks! if there is no other way. I should do that in "onDestory()".

Comment: Um.. I found this link.(sorry for editing. I'm writing with a mobile phone)
(http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=9ACF6480A5FD9DDFEDE7ED6CD35C97EF?recipeId=1370)

From above link. "Thread.setDaemon(true)" is one of the alternative way. By setting thread as daemon thread, your thread will be stopped when main thread is terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dwnz Thank you!!
Finally, I call "onDestory()" method in MainActivity. In onDestory(), if isFinishing() of Activity is true, it will be terminated(Of course, this is not "necessary and sufficient condition".)

Answer (score 0):

you can create thread like :

```
Thread  th;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
//do your stuff             
}
});
th.run()           //to start thread
}


public void requestShutDown(){
 if(th.isAlive())
{
th.yield();        //to close thread
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But my explain is not enough for you. In my case, thread in Singleton instance. Not in specific activity...