# How to Stop Thread

Tags: java, android

I want to stop my thread if record were fetched please help me out. Here is my code.

```
 if (dialog==null) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AgentProgress.this, "",
                "Fetching Records...", true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    loadnames load1 = new loadnames();
                    load1.execute("");

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //this is a MUST
                }
            }


        }).start();


    }
```

In this loadnames are class that fetches name if it fetches then thread would stop.

Comment: @AZEEM AHMED refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505707/android-best-and-safe-way-to-stop-thread

Comment: check [this example](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/THI05-J.+Do+not+use+Thread.stop()+to+terminate+threads) about why to use `interrupt()` method and not `stop()` method to stop the thread

Comment: post your code for `loadnames `

Comment: load names class is that is load user from webservices.