# control Service while recording audio

Tags: android, android-service, audio-recording

I want to start a service and record the audio and then close the activity, but keeps recording, and then open the activity and stop recording.

this is my service :

```
public class RecorderService extends Service {

private Thread mThread;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startRecording();
        }
    });
    mThread.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mThread = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

this is my code to start and stop the service:

```
 Button recordAudioButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recordAudioButton);
    recordAudioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecorderService.class));

        }
    });

    Button buttonPLay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPLay);
    buttonPLay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecorderService.class));

        }
    });
```

it starts but when I stop the service it doesn't stop . What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How do you understand that service doesn't stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that although you set the `mThread = null;` you also need to stop it first.

See [android best and safe way to stop thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505707/android-best-and-safe-way-to-stop-thread) for more details on stopping a thread.

For you example try changing the `onStartCommand` and `onDestory` to:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                return;
            }

            startRecording();
        }
    });
    mThread.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mThread.interrupt();
    mThread = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: That check `if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())` - almost senseless in that place of code